# Which Version Control systems integrate with Bitrix24?

Tags: version-control, bitrix

I'm about to embark on an HTML remediation project. My client is using Bitrix as a task/issue tracker, but isn't currently using anything for Source/Version control.

I've searched up 'Bitrix' and assume that they mean 'Bitrix24'.

Is there a Version Control system which integrates with Bitrix24?

I'd like:

1. To be able to browse to Version Control from within the Bitrix interface
2. To link to commit hashes, line numbers and (release) tags from within Bitrix tasks/issues
3. To use Git rather than SVN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitrix has no such feature out from the box - see old topic on Bitrix support forum - https://www.bitrix24.com/support/forum/forum47/topic10287/

I think it is because of CRM-nature of the Bitrix.

You could link your task/issues in Bitrix with commits in GitLab/Bitbucket using third-party hooks:

- for GitLab - https://github.com/lolweb/bxGitlab
- for BitBucket - https://github.com/Web-LLC/bxGitlab

You could also try to link GitHub commits using Zappier + Bitrix24 free Zappier integration App https://www.bitrix24.com/apps/?app=b24io.zapieren

I have not used them, so don't know if they really work.

Also Bitrix24 has API https://www.bitrix24.com/apps/dev.php to build any integration, but it is a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I haven't tried web hooks or Zapier, but will consider them if the project goes ahead.